# Train, Save and Load a Tensorflow Model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Refer to [this](https://github.com/FelixMohr/Deep-learning-with-Python/blob/master/DCGAN-MNIST.ipynb) to train a GAN model for MNIST dataset, I want to save a model and restore it for further prediction. After having some understanding of [Saving and Importing a Tensorflow Model](https://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/) I am able to save and restore some variables of inputs and outputs but for [this](https://github.com/FelixMohr/Deep-learning-with-Python/blob/master/DCGAN-MNIST.ipynb) network I am able to save the model only after some specific iterations and not able to predict some output.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: After saving the above model how can i predict results later as this model dont use any variable for prediction but a function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) guide? It explains very clearly how to load and save tensorflow models in all possible formats.

Comment: No i didnt refer to this guide

Comment: Does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to ML, I'd recommend you give Keras a try first, which is much easier to use. See https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model, pretty much you can use:

```
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

to save your model to disk.

```
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

to load your model and make prediction

Comment: I am used to keras its so easy but i am new to TF so i have asked the question